# php multidimensional array for html table

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, forms

ok consider I have the following data from my database:

```
string '20' 
string '14' 
float 6

string '15'
string '14' 
float 10
```

20 & 15 are project ids
14 is the user id 
and the floats are hours

I need to compile this data to be printed to a HTML table. The answer seems to be a multidimensional array.

so I assume this will look like this:

```
array (size 3)

0=> [project codes]
1=> [data (floats)] 
2=> [user id's]
```

Is it possible to recursively search my returned mysql results for the project code and the user id and pop the float into the correct position in this case:

for project 20 and user id 14 insert 6 hours [20][6][14].

Comment: presumably you stored the query results in an array, so yes, you can access whatever you want in that array.

Comment: If result stores in php array  then yes it's possible

Comment: So how would I print only the data to td tags? echo $array[1][$x] (assuming for loop) 

I already have a table with the list of users on the x axis and the project titles on the Y axis @MarcB

Comment: `<td><?php echo $whatever_you_want ?></td>`.

Answer (score 0):

load the array from the database "fetch loop"

```
$arr = array("project"=>$row['project_id'], "data"=>$row['data'], "userid"=>$row['user_id']);
```

display the data loop

```
foreach ($arr as $valarr){
   echo $valarr['data']; // your tds' line with the data
}
```

Comment: This is really useful thanks, but the foreach loop is losing the key defined in $arr. Therefore 'undefined index'

Comment: make sure the array is properly loaded, like: $arr[] = array("project"=>"proj2", "data"=>"5678", "userid"=>"200"); then the $valarr['data'] in the foreach should be good